# Min-Max heap delete max element

Tags: c++, data-structures, heap, minmax-heap

I'm confused about the final image after a delete-max operation. When 87 is deleted does 48 get brought to the spot that 87 once held? Does the rest of the tree not change after?

[Min-max heap original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RivLx.png)

Answer (score 1):

No. 78 would be bubbled up to fill the spot that 87 once held.

You should read the original paper: Min-Max Heaps and Generalized Priority Queues: http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/staffpriv/mike/Papers/MinMaxHeaps/MinMaxHeaps.pdf